# Is this behavior of std::expected with move-only types a MSVC bug or undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std, c++23, std-expected

I've encountered a curious issue with my C++ code when compiling with Microsoft Visual Studio's MSVC compiler, and I'm trying to determine whether it's a compiler bug or undefined behavior according to the C++ standard.

The minimal reproducible example is below:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <expected>

struct UniqueHandle {
    UniqueHandle() { 
        val = nullptr; 
    }
    ~UniqueHandle() { 
        std::cout << "~UniqueHandle(" << val << ")" << std::endl; 
    }
    UniqueHandle(void* val) : val(val) {}
    UniqueHandle(UniqueHandle&& other) { 
        std::swap(val, other.val);
    }
    UniqueHandle& operator=(UniqueHandle&& other) {
        std::swap(val, other.val);
        return *this;
    }
    void* val;
};
std::expected<UniqueHandle, int> foo() {
    return UniqueHandle {};
}
int main() {
    auto exp_res = foo();
    UniqueHandle result {};
    if (exp_res) {
        result = std::move(exp_res.value());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program produces the following output with the VS 2022 toolchain in the Debug build:

```
~UniqueHandle(CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC)
~UniqueHandle(0000000000000000)
~UniqueHandle(0000000000000000)
```

In the Release build, the first line is some garbage value. I fail to see where this value comes from. However, it works as expected when compiled by g++, live example here:

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zMh5W6MMj

Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: What happens with clang?

Comment: `I fail to see where this value comes from.` From your broken move constructor implementation. `UniqueHandle(UniqueHandle&& other) { 
        std::swap(val, other.val);
    }` You never initialize `val` before swapping it with the others `val`.

Comment: `0xCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC` is used by MSVC to show uninitialized memory.

Comment: @tkausl Thanks, that explains it. I see this is a stupid mistake on my end.

Comment: tip: use [`std::exchange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) for stuff that move. It helps avoid the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your move constructor `this->val` is uninitialised. The `std::swap` therefore sets `other.val` to this uninitialised value. MSVC's debug runtime [sets uninitialised memory to `0xCCCCCCCC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values) so this is the value that is printed. You can sort of see the same behaviour in GCC by adding a member initialiser: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hMa9Ka9cb

Move constructors can be implemented with [`std::exchange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) to help avoid this problem:

```
UniqueHandle(UniqueHandle&& other): val{std::exchange(other.val, nullptr)} { 
}
```

By always using member initialisers it's clearer that all members have been initialised before use and the new value for the moved from member is explicitly stated.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is the perfect solution.
But I would use **default+swap idiom**(my made-up idiom) in general case:

```
void UniqueHandler::swap(UniqueHandler&);
UniqueHandler::UniqueHandler(UniqueHandler&& rvalue)
: UniqueHandler{/*delegate to default*/}
{ this->swap(rvalue); }; //swap
```

This is a use case of delegating constructors.